# Trouble with gcovr exclusions

Tags: c++, code-coverage, gcovr

I am running gcovr (3.3) on an out of source build like:

`gcovr --root=/path/to/source --object-directory=/path/to/build`

Now I want to exclude two different things from the report:

1) Any `.cpp` files that have "Test" in their name

`--exclude='.*Test.*'` does not seem to work

2) All source files in a directory (say `/path/to/source/MyModule/`)

`--exclude='/path/to/source/MyModule/.*'` does not seem to work.

`--exclude-directories='/path/to/source/MyModule'` also does not seem to work.

**My questions**

a) what is `--exclude-directories` for since it seems like you (should) be able to exclude a directory with the right regex passed to `--exclude`?

b) Any suggestions about why the `--exclude`s do not work as expected? Perhaps these are not the right kind/style of regular expressions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both of these options are not well documented, so the main source of knowledge is [source code](https://github.com/gcovr/gcovr/blob/master/scripts/gcovr).

> a) what is --exclude-directories for since it seems like you (should) be able to exclude a directory with the right regex passed to --exclude?

`--exclude-directories` option used by gcovr to skip directories by it's name, not fullpath. It can be verified if you check the gcovr's source code. Magic is done in `def link_walker(path)` function:

```
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(
        os.path.abspath(path), followlinks=True
    ):
        for exc in options.exclude_dirs:
            for d in dirs:
                m = exc.search(d)
```

According to the [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) documentation, `dirs` is a list of the names of the subdirectories. E.g. to skip all directories starts with `MyMod` use `--exclude-directories='MyMod.*'`.

> b) Any suggestions about why the --excludes do not work as expected? Perhaps these are not the right kind/style of regular expressions?

Your regular expression is correct. It's typical Python's regex.

To understand what is going on at `--exclude` option it's useful to enable `-v` output. With this option enabled, output should have lots of lines:

```
currdir      /cygdrive/f/test/path/to/source
gcov_fname   myfile.cpp.gcov
           ['        -', '    0', 'Source', 'myfile.cpp\n']
source_fname /cygdrive/f/test/path/to/source/myfile.gcda
root         /cygdrive/f/test/path/to/source
fname        /cygdrive/f/test/path/to/source/myfile.cpp
Parsing coverage data for file /cygdrive/f/test/path/to/source/myfile.cpp
```

This output produced by [`def process_gcov_data(data_fname, covdata, source_fname, options)`](https://github.com/gcovr/gcovr/blob/master/scripts/gcovr#L484) function. If you check the source code you will see the following:

```
for exc in options.exclude:
    if (filtered_fname is not None and exc.match(filtered_fname)) or \
            exc.match(fname) or \
            exc.match(os.path.abspath(fname))
```

Exclude filter applies to `fname` printed above. It's the absolute filepath. Also it applies to all files which have coverage data. If file was excluded the following line should be in output (`-v` option required):

```
Excluding coverage data for file /cygdrive/f/test/path/to/source/myfile.cpp
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. Two small follow ups: 1) I still don't understand the difference between `--exclude='.*/MyMod.*'` and `--exclude-directories='MyMod.*'`? 2) Can you explain the difference between `--exclude` and  `--gcov-exclude=`?

Comment: 2) `--gcov-exclude` excludes gcov data files. It applied against `myfile.cpp.gcov` files. `--exclude` excludes `cpp` files.

Comment: but isn't there exactly one `.gcov` file per `.cpp` file?

Comment: Right, but some times you need to process existent gcov data with `--use-gcov-files` option. In this case `--gcov-exclude` is the only option to exclude data files.

Comment: What would be the use case for specifying `--use-gcov-files`? Why would you not just use `--root` and `--object-directory` like I'm doing?

Comment: It's used in case you don't have `cpp` files and only gcov data files available.

Comment: 1) `--exclude-directories='MyMod.*'` excludes all directories starts with `MyMod`. `--exclude='.*/MyMod.*'` excludes all the `.cpp` files which absolute path matches this regex. If you use the second one instead of the first it can skip `path/file/MyModule.cpp` instead of the folder `MyModule`.

Comment: Sure, but you could just craft the regex to match a folder (something like `--exclude='.*/MyModule/.*'`), right? So I guess this is just really a helper then? I just I'm just trying to make sure I'm correctly that everything you can do with `--exclude-directory` you can also do with `--exclude` and the appropriate regex.

Comment: Right, it's like a helper function

Comment: how to mention multiple directories under --exlude-directories option? seems this is not working for me --exclude-directories=test,thrift.* , here I am trying to exclude test and thrift directory.

Comment: @RamkumarD the `--exclude` flag can be used multiple times: https://github.com/gcovr/gcovr/issues/151#issuecomment-370941127